# How to sort random strings in a file via shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, cut

I have a file with these strings at random. How can i sort them horizontally and also eliminate any duplicates.

```
cat file
ticket-125788   ticket-126824    ticket-126957   ticket-126914
ticket-127220
ticket-125948                       ticket-126914

ticket-127030
ticket-127262
 ticket-127012  ticket-127022
ticket-127035


     ticket-126961
ticket-127024
```

`Desired output:`

```
ticket-125788 ticket-126824 ticket-126957 ticket-127220 ticket-125948 ticket-126914 ticket-127030 ticket-127262 ticket-127012 ticket-127022 ticket-127035 ticket-126961 ticket-127024
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
$ grep -o '\S*' file | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
ticket-125788 ticket-125948 ticket-126824 ticket-126914 ticket-126957 ...
```

- `grep -o` puts each ticket on a separate line.
- `sort -u` sorts and removes duplicates.
- `tr '\n' ' '` flatten the output to single line.

Alternatively using `xargs`:

```
$ xargs -n1 < file | sort -u | xargs
ticket-125788 ticket-125948 ticket-126824 ticket-126914 ticket-126957 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Whole idea is to `grep` every «string» and then collapse it to single line via `tr`.

```
$> grep -P -o "[0-9a-z-]+" file | sort --unique | tr '\n' ' '
ticket-125788 ticket-125948 ticket-126824 ticket-126914 ticket-126957 ticket-126961 ticket-127012 ticket-127022 ticket-127024 ticket-127030 ticket-127035 ticket-127220 ticket-127262
```